# Getting node name namespace from rclcpp

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi is there a way to get to a node namespace in some clean way before that node is constructed using make shared?
Processing argv doesn't seem like a good idea :/

Let's say

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  rclcpp_init(argc, argv);
  // i want to get to the namespace and name here
  auto node = std::make_shared<MyCustomNode>();
  // currently this is the way I do this, but this is
  auto ns = node->get_namespace();
  auto name = node->get_name()
}
```

to get the namespace I could create some simple node, but that will collide with my desired one, when I want to get the name (I think?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378892/getting-node-name-namespace-from-rclcpp/) by [Serafadam](https://answers.ros.org/users/52568/serafadam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2021-05-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did some digging, and while there might have been something I missed, I do not believe it is possible. The function that gets the namespace at the lower level is `rcl_node_get_namespace()` but that still takes in a node field. Looking into its implementation does indeed require that a node exists so there's not some simplifed code you could easily rip out to find it.

Source: https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/b6f0ef2df5454208bc5904191558e1b169dfbe18/rcl/src/rcl/node.c#L440-L447

The creation of this is called on the node rcl init functions, which then is called when a node is created. Digging in deeper leads to the RMW layer at which I stopped trying to track it. If you need to go that low level, you're not in for a good time.

Edit: Found where it remaps the namespace in rcl https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/b6f0ef2df5454208bc5904191558e1b169dfbe18/rcl/src/rcl/node.c#L228 but as you can see, it relies on the global_arguments, which I believe is the global namespace potential remaps (if you're trying to find the remapped name) but that requires a valid context to exist, which is created with the node.

tl;dr: No, you need a node object to exist so that there's at least a context in the process to gather that information.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3